# Steps for customize profile page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, user-profile

I'm working on a school project and I never use drupal.

So I want to display some users informations into their profile page like:

- Username
- Profile picture
- City
- ...

I want them to update their infos (profile picture too).

Futhermore **I want to be able to custom HTML structure of this page**.

I red post saying that I should use **Panels** or **Views** but I'm so confused with these choices

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I catch up new technology, I used to read some source codes other programmers wrote. Fortunatly, Drupal gives up some sample source codes like user profile page and so on. I recommend you to read source code below and brash up your skills.

https://www.drupal.org/project/commons